# PHP cannot find anything in LDAP (while python can)

Tags: php, python, active-directory, ldap

Help me,please. I have some problems with my php code, while trying to search user in ldap.
On the same VM I execute python code without problems, searching for user completes successfully. Obvious, it isn't network connection problems.
LDAP filter is the same in php and in python code.

Also I noticed that when I look in output of tcpdump, executed in the same time as my php code, I see that count of packets is much less, then when I execute tcpdump in parallel with python code (7 packets while executing php vs 729 packs while executing python code)

**php code**:

```
<?php
$ldapConnectionId = ldap_connect("domain.controller.example");
$LDAP_USER='domain\username';
$LDAP_PSWD='userpass';
$ldaptree = 'DC=X,DC=X,DC=X';
ldap_set_option($ldapConnectionId, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapConnectionId, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, false);

$bnd = ldap_bind($ldapConnectionId, $LDAP_USER, $LDAP_PSWD);
$filter='(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))';
$ldapSearchResults = ldap_search($ldapConnectionId, $ldaptree, $filter);
$ldapEntries = ldap_get_entries($ldapConnectionId, $ldapSearchResults);
echo $ldapEntries["count"]." entries found\n";
ldap_close($ldapConnectionId);
?>
```

**python code**, that works properly on the same VM:

```
AD_SERVER='domain.controller.example'
AD_USER='domain\username'
AD_PASS='userpass'
server=Server(AD_SERVER,get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server,user=AD_USER,password=AD_PASS, auto_bind=True)
conn.start_tls()
conn.search(search_base='dc=X,dc=X,dc=X',
search_filter='(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))',
attributes=['distinguishedName'])
```

After executing this code (php7.3 as interpreter), I get  "0 entries found"
What may be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to do `ldap_connect` by specifying explicitly the port (389 by default) as a second parameter. Did you try to debug `$ldapConnectionId` value?

Comment: Try different versions. `ldap_set_option($ldapConnectionId, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);`

Comment: LDAP version is 3.

Comment: Thanks, @mitkosoft. I turned on the debug mode and find an error:
```
res_errno: 10, res_error: <0000202B: RefErr: DSID-03100781, data 0, 1 access points
        ref 1: 'X.X.X'
```
So, it means I made a mistake in my $ldaptree variable. 
[For other guys, who doesn't know, how to enable the debug mode: 
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);  ]
Good luck!